# Unable to transfer domains into Google Cloud Domains project due to quota exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, domain-transferring

This year we started using Google Cloud Domains to manage our domain collection. Over the months it has been a nice experience using the "gcloud domains registrations transfer" CLI command. And all domains transferred via this method also appear on our domains.google.com account as "managed by Cloud Domains". We have created a GCP project specifically for managing these inactive domains (not connected to any given project and essentially parked domains) that we own.

Unfortunately after another round of transfers was due I started experiencing repetitive failures in attempting to transfer domains into our account. The error message displayed is:

> Quota limit 'DomainRegistrationsPerProject' has been exceeded. Limit:
> 100 in global.

Therefore it appears there is a 100 domains limitation per GCP project on Cloud Domains. Now it seems our only recourse is to either create an additional GCP project to continue transferring domains...or handle everything via Domains.google.com's transfer interface. Much more nimble/quick to handle things via the gcloud CLI command and if there was a similar way to use a CLI cmd directly with domains.google.com I would.

Not sure if there's anything else that can be done...but if anyone has any suggestions or recommendations on how I could possibly get this domain registrations quota lifted it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The solution is to request a quota increase: https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#about_increase_requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be best to request for a [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#about_increase_requests). You may follow this documentation to [request a higher quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota) so you can continue doing the Cloud Domains transfer. Quota increase requests are typically completed within 2-3 business days. You are sent an email when your request is received, to which you can respond if you have questions or want to provide additional information. You then get another email after the request is processed, notifying you whether the quota increase was approved or denied. The email provides the effective date of the increase, if applicable.

Comment: good call, I'll definitely give that a go and request a quota increase. Much appreciated.